# AFNetworking making requests while offline

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

So I am trying to handle posting something to server and this works while the iPhone is with internet. Now I need to handle the request if there is no internet. I tried a bit of code below tho handle operation queue in relation to reachability. I dont think I need cache as I'm posting. What am I missing here? I want the request to be sent soon as the internet is available. While I might be doing something else in the app. The only thing I suspect is that my OperationManager is initialised in each request like POST or GET so maybe the previous one could be wipeout. But that is operation manager and not operation queue.

```
- (void)sendRequestPOST:(NSString *)url parameters:(NSMutableDictionary *)parameters {
NSLog(@"POST Request URL : %@", url);
NSLog(@"POST Request Body : %@", parameters);
__block AFHTTPRequestOperation *opr;
[[AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager] setEnabled:YES];

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
AFJSONRequestSerializer *jsonRS = [[AFJSONRequestSerializer alloc] init];
[manager setRequestSerializer:jsonRS];
[[manager requestSerializer] setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[[manager requestSerializer] setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[[manager responseSerializer] setAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/html", nil]];

[[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {
    NSLog(@"Reachability: %@", AFStringFromNetworkReachabilityStatus(status));
}];
NSOperationQueue *operationQueue = manager.operationQueue;
[manager.reachabilityManager setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {
    switch (status) {
        case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWWAN:
        case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWiFi:
            [operationQueue setSuspended:NO];
            break;
        case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusNotReachable:
        default:
            [operationQueue setSuspended:YES];
            break;
    }
}];

[manager.reachabilityManager startMonitoring];


[manager POST:url parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.mainView animated:YES];
    opr = operation;
    [self.mainView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    NSLog(@"POST Response : %@",responseObject);
    NSLog(@"Status Code : %ld",(long)[[operation response] statusCode]);
    if([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didFinish:dictInfo:)]) {
        [AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager].enabled = NO;
        [_delegate didFinish:self dictInfo:(NSMutableDictionary *)responseObject];
         NSLog(@"Request finished");
    }
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    opr = operation;
    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.mainView animated:YES];
    [self.mainView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    NSLog(@"POST Error: %@", error);

    //    [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager].operatonQueue addOperation:operation];

    if([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(failRequest:statusCode:)]) {
        [AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager].enabled = NO;
        [_delegate failRequest:self statusCode:[[operation response] statusCode]];
        NSLog(@"Request failed");
    }
}];}
```

Comment: There're 2 things I would suggest:
1. As a good rule - don't perform any action (-in your case -  `[operationQueue setSuspended:NO]`;) depending on the reachability status  **before** actually making a network call.
2. In the failure block I'd check the reachability and if it is the cause of the failure I would hold on to the `operation` temporarily (`NSMutableSet` maybe) and every time the reachability changes would check for any "pending" `operations` first to run them (and don't forget to clean up).

Comment: use reachability as @IslamQ. said.

Comment: I would appreciate any example for the second part, I understand the first.

Comment: @arkmon Have you found any solution to this? I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a Swift pod that allows network requests to be wrapped in a way that they can be enqueued regardless of current network connectivity and saved until it goes through - https://cocoapods.org/pods/OfflineRequestManager. Might be useful to anybody seeing this.

The simplest use case would look something like the following, though most actual cases (saving to disk, specific request data, etc.) will have a few more hoops to jump through:

```
import OfflineRequestManager

class SimpleRequest: OfflineRequest {
    func perform(completion: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
        doMyNetworkRequest(withCompletion: { response, error in
            handleResponse(response)
            completion(error)
        })
    }
}
///////
OfflineRequestManager.defaultManager(queueRequest: SimpleRequest())
```